# Change from one navigation controller to another

Tags: ios, ios4, uinavigationcontroller

I have application with 2 tab bars. In second tab bar I have navigation controller. I want to change this navigation controller to another navigation controller when "Change" button is pressed. How can I do that? Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to replace the View Controller in the TabBar using the `viewControllers` property of `UITabBarController` or `setViewControllers:animated:`if you want to add some animation.

But maybe you should think of having 2 views in a controller of yours and hide/show them when you click a button, maybe even pushing/popping view controllers without animation (`pushViewController:yourController animated:NO`) on the navigation stack of your navigation controller and just hide the back button (`self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES`)